# How to check if a module is enabled/disabled in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, multistore

I have 2 stores views and a custom module, lat say module X with an observer.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
       
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        
         $urlInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
         
        //check if the crrent url not belong to the clubshop
        if($urlInterface->getCurrentUrl() =='https://www.storeview1.com/'){
            return true;
        }
        if(!strpos($urlInterface->getCurrentUrl(), "club_login" )){
            
            if($customerSession->getMyValue()==1){
                return true;
                 
            }else{
                
            //redirect if sotreview 2
             $url = $urlInterface->getUrl('club_login');
                 $observer->getControllerAction()
                            ->getResponse()
                            ->setRedirect($url);
                            return false;
            }
            
        }
    
    }
```

For storeview no 1. this module in disabled(Storev-Config-Developer-Advanced) and for storeview no 2 this module is enabled.

Even the module is disabled on sotreview no 1, the observer still work on both stores and it redirect me.

What i tried to do, is to check if the module x is or no enabled on the storeview no 1, to avoid the extecution of this function.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: how can one module be disabled on one store view and enabled for another? you mean the output is disabled from system->configuration->advanced?

Comment: yes. I updated my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From `Storev-Config-Developer-Advanced` you only disable the output of a module and not the module itself. So the plugins the preferences and the event observers are still taken into consideration.
If you want to detect if a module output is disabled you can do this:

change your class constructor to provide an instance of `Magento\Framework\Module\Manager` as a dependency:

```
protected $moduleManager;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    ...
}
```

then you can call in your `execute` method this:

```
if ($this->moduleManager->isOutputEnabled('Vendor_Module')) {
    //the module output is enabled
} else {
    //the module output is disabled
}
```

you might not need the `else` part

Comment: great. thank you, but how this will know when is enabled and when is disabled? For example if a go on storeview 1 url how this code will know if on this store the output is disabled and for the other one is disabled?

Comment: it will check the configuration setting. But I just found something. Starting version 2.2.0 the output disabling is not possible anymore. So maybe you should rethink your architecture to take into consideration a custom yes/no setting instead of the module output. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/Manager.php#L69

Comment: Ok. thank you very much for your help. I will take this in consideration

Comment: @Marius this function is deprecated. One should use `$this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Vendor_Module')` instead. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 15):

You can check module status by below command:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

You can see the list of enables modules.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want to make this check inside of observer.

Comment: you can check it by app/etc/config.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method `isEnabled` to check if your module is enabled, if your code is enabled when you use this command below, so you can use this method to do the same check:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

First thing, add the class into your module.

```
protected $moduleManager;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    ...
}
```

Then implement this check:

```
if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Vendor_Module')) {
    //the module is enabled
} else {
    //the module is disabled
}
```